# Access relation in forelse on the same model - laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

i have a question about accessing relation in laravel model. I have category model which has relation to translation model and category model(same model/itself  - one category can be displayed in other categories using pivot table CategoryToCategory):

category model:

```
    public function childCategories(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Category',
            'App\Models\CategoryToCategory',
            'id_parent_category', 
            'id',  
            'id',
            'id_category'); 
    }

    public function translation($locale = null)
    {
        if ($locale == null) {
            $locale = \App::getLocale();
        }
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\CategoryLanguage', 'id_category', 'id')->where('locale', '=', $locale);
    }
```

Now i take current category + translation + child categories:

```
$category = Category::with('translation', 'childCategories')->active()->where('id', $id)->first();
```

And display all childs names:

```
@forelse($category->childCategories as $category)
   {{ $category->translation->name }}
@endforelse
```

I works **but** each child category makes another query to get translation(it's not loaded for elements in forelse). So how to load relation "translation" in category model which is foreaching loaded relation?

I could query model CategoryToCategory to get all child categories + load translation for that model and result be the same:

```
$categories = CategoryToCategory::with('translation')->where('id_parent_category', $id)->get();
```

And there will be one query for translations. Still i'm curious about using first solution instead query categoryToCategory.

Any ideas?

Have a nice day!

Comment: Try like the documentation:

$translation = Category::find($id)->translation;

dd($translation);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eager load a distant relationship you can use the dot notation like so:

```
$category = Category::with('translation', 'childCategories.translations')
    ->active()
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->first();
```

This is known as "nested eager loading" and is referenced in the docs here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading